# Item visible in Document Library, but not available to download

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, out-of-the-box

I have this requirement where some files in a document library file must be visible in the library list, but not available to be downloaded.

I know how to implement this with custom components, handlers, etc.

Just wondering what is the best way to leverage OOB components / functionality to achieve this without writing too much code.

Any Ideas

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is "Information Rights Management".

You have to restrict the access to "View Listitems" ("A user can read the document, but cannot copy or modify its content.").

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/apply-information-rights-management-to-a-list-or-library-HA010154148.aspx